# NumberFormatException when form is submited to spring controller

Tags: java, spring, forms, hibernate, submit

In my current spring project, when I try submit this form:

```
 <form role="form" class="form" action="/Destaque/cadastra" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<field-box>
  <div>
    <div>              
      <div>
        <label>Produto</label><select class="form-control" name="listaDeProdutos[]" multiple="multiple" rows="7"><option value="1">one</option><option value="2">two</option><option value="3">three</option><option value="4">four</option><option value="5">five</option><option value="6">six</option><option value="7">seven</option><option value="8">eight</option><option value="9">nine</option><option value="10">ten</option><option value="11">eleven</option><option value="12">twelve</option></select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</field-box>
<field-box>
        <label>Titulo</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="titulo" />
</field-box>
<field-box>
        <label>Resumo</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="resumo" />
</field-box>
<field-box>
        <label>Valor</label><input type="text" class="form-control valida" pattern="[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}" name="valor" />
</field-box>
<field-box>
        <label>Descrição</label><textarea class="summernote" name="descricao"></textarea>
</field-box>
<field-box>
        <label>Capa do destaque</label><input type="file" class="form-control" name="icone" />
</field-box>
<field-box>
        <label>Validade</label><input type="text" class="form-control valida" pattern="[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}" name="validade" />
</field-box>
<field-box>
        <label>destaque ativo</label><input type="checkbox" name="ativo" />
</field-box>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Cadastrar</button>

<div id="yes" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="display: none;">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-hide="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
  <span class="text">Cadastro efetuado com sucesso</span>
</div>

<div id="not" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display: none;">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-hide="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
  <span class="text"></span>
</div>
```

to this entity class:

```
@Entity
@Form
@FormPublic
@Order(value = 5)
public class Destaque extends Model {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Order(value = 1)
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name="listaDeProdutosEmDestaque", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_destaque")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_produto")})
  @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
  @Order(value = 2)
  @Select(label = "Produto", classe=Produto.class)
  private List<Produto> listaDeProdutos;

  @Order(value = 3)
  @Input(label = "Titulo")
  @Column(length = 100)
  private String titulo;

  @Order(value = 4)
  @Input(label = "Resumo")
  @Column(length = 100)
  private String resumo;

  @Order(value = 5)
  @Input(label = "Valor", pattern = "[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}")
  private Float valor;

  @Order(value = 6)
  @Textarea(label = "Descrição")
  @Column(length = 131072)
  private String descricao;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "banner")
  @Order(value = 7)
  @Input(label = "Capa do destaque", type="file")
  private Picture icone;

  @Order(value = 8)
  @Input(label = "Validade", pattern = "[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}")
  private Date validade;

  @Order(value = 9)
  @Checkbox(label = "destaque ativo")
  private Boolean ativo;
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:993)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:926)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:749)
        at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:645)
        at org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder.doBind(WebDataBinder.java:189)
        at org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder.bind(ServletRequestDataBinder.java:106)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.bindRequestParameters(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:150)
        at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

ANyone can see what's wrong here?

ps.: the submission is handled by this method:

controller:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "cadastra", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public void cadastra(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result, @RequestParam(value="icone", required=false) MultipartFile icone, @RequestParam(value="fotos", required=false) MultipartFile fotos[], @RequestParam(value="arquivo", required=false) MultipartFile arquivo[]) throws Exception {
    serv.cadastra(object);
    serv.upload(object, icone);
    serv.upload_multiplo(object, fotos);
    serv.upload_jar(object, arquivo);
  }
```

service

```
  @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_'+#this.this.name)")
  @Transactional
  public void cadastra(E object) {
    dao.insert(object);
  }
```

dao class:

```
public void insert(E object) {
    EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(object);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve this issue adding this Property Editor class to the project:

```
@Component
public class ProdutoEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
  @Override
  public void setAsText(String text) {
    if (!text.equals("")) {
      ProdutoService serv = new ProdutoService();
      ApplicationContextHolder.getContext().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(serv);
      Produto produto = serv.getObject(text);
      setValue(produto);
    } else {
      setValue(null);
    }
  }
}
```

which work with this select code:

```
<select class="form-control" name="listaDeProdutos" multiple="multiple" rows="7">
    ...
    <option value="1">one</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the stack trace(`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`), it appears that what is happening is that when you submit the form, one of the number inputs of the form is still blank, so when you try to cast the string input to a number, it throws the error.

This can be fixed by defaulting the number inputs of the form to a number (e.g., zero) so that the form won't be submitted with empty number inputs.

Comment: But I am filling all the fields of the form before submit. Maybe the application is missing some of the values?

Comment: It's hard to say without more info, but based purely on the stack trace, you are binding a double value to some form input, and the error is due to the input being empty. If all numerical inputs in the form are never empty (i.e., ""), then another possibility I can think of is that after you read the value you are clearing it to "", and the 2-way binding then throws the error because it tries to update that value.